# Update Columns in Laravel with Multiple Data field

Tags: php, laravel

**I have a form like this**

```
<form method="POST" action="/path/{{ $tran->transid }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="pono[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Purchase Order No">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="10"></td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" name="sbmt" value="Save Information" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

**I have a controller:**

```
public function poPost(Request $request, $transid)
{
    foreach ($request['pono'] as $key => $pno) {
        $p = $request['pono'][$key];
        Model::where('transid', $transid)->update(['poNo' => $p]);
    }

    return redirect('/path')->with('success', 'Update is successful');
}
```

I am expecting the column to be updated based on what is in each of the form field. However, the result of the above is that it updates the column "poNo" with the last value in the form. Please,what am i doing wrong? I need it to update each row with the value of each field instead of the last field.[image]

Comment: Why are you using `$request['pono'][$key]` instead of just using `$pno`?

Comment: @RossWilson: I have tried using it as $request['pono'] as $pno), but did not work.Please, guide me better, i am just perfecting laravel

Comment: You're updating the same column `poNo` on all rows in every loop of `$request->input("pono");`, so the only value that will be saved is the last one. This is more of a database issue than a logic issue; how do you expect to save multiple `poNo` values for a single Model row when you only have one `poNo` column? Either need to implode the values to a CSV, or create a linking table.

Comment: @TimLewis: Please, i am just matering laravel. I use procedural php and i can swiftly do this in it. Migrating to laravel is a learning curve. So, with pono[] in the form field, tells me that it is an array of data. i want to update column 'poNo; in the DB with each of the field, that are with different values

Comment: In that case can you show how you would implement this with procedural php. At the minute your code is essentially saying update the row where `transid`=`$transid` and set `poNo` = `$p` so therefore in the next loop it will update the `poNo` to be the next value of `$p`. Is there meant to be another where in your query?

Comment: @RossWilson: it would have been something like this:if(isset($_POST["savebtn"])){
 foreach($_POST["pono"] as $rec=> $value){
  $po = $_POST["pono"][$rec];
  $id =  $_POST["id"][$rec];
   $reqid = $_GET["transid"];
  $query = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE table SET poNo='$po' WHERE id='$id' AND transid='$reqid'");
  }

Comment: In the example above you have an extra field (`$_POST["id"]`) that you've not included in the form in your question.

Comment: @RossWilson: SOrry for that, i have incorporated that into it and still updating with the last value in the form field:  foreach($request['pono'] as $key => $pno){
      
         Model::where('id',$request['ids'])->update(['poNo'=>$pno]);  
        }

Comment: Can you update the form in your question to show how you're adding the id values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177748/discussion-between-dave-and-ross-wilson).

Answer (score 0):

Every time in the loop You are updating the same record in your database table.
So, The last value will override the previous ones.
If you want to update different rows . you need to update where(different ids) not the same id every time
please be more specific about what are you want to do .. and give us your table structure with some records if this answer isn't enough for you

note: no need for :

```
$p = $request['pono'][$key];
```

you can use `$pno` instead :

```
foreach ($request['pono'] as $key => $pno) {
        Model::where('transid', $transid)->update(['poNo' => $pno]);
    }
```

Comment: I tried that, but still updated with the last value of the form. See modification  <td><input type="text" name="pono[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Purchase Order No" value="{{ $tran->poNo }}"></td> foreach($request['pono'] as $key => $pno){
      
         Model::where('id',$request['ids'])->update(['poNo'=>$pno]);  
        }
       <input type="hidden" name="ids[]" value="{{ $tran->id }}">